# Query result to DataFrame using Pyspark: ValueError: Length of object does not match with length of Field

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-rds

I was running a query from RDS and converting the query into DataFrame using Pyspark.

Here is my code

```
query= "Select * from profit"
profit=pd.read_sql(query, con=db_connection)

StructureSechma=StructType([
   StructField("id",IntegerType(), True),
   StructField("type",StringType(), False),
   StructField("userId",IntegerType(), True),
   StructField("amount",FloatType(), False),
   StructField("sell",StringType(), False),
   StructField("buy",StringType(), False),
   StructField("createdAt",DateType(), False),
   StructField("updatedAt",DateType(), False)
    ])
   profit_df = spark.createDataFrame(profit,,schema=StructureSechma)
```

I'm getting this issue

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 748, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 413, in _createFromLocal
    data = list(data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 730, in prepare
    verify_func(obj)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1391, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1370, in verify_struct
    "length of fields (%d)" % (len(obj), len(verifiers))))
ValueError: Length of object (25) does not match with length of fields (8)
```

Any Suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This needs data to analyse. You need to isolate the data which is causing this. Try running query `select * from profit limit1`. If it results in error then post the output of the query as seen in SQL.

Comment: did you try without using the schema ? technically, spark can infer the schema directly from pandas

Comment: Regarding the error, i believe profit is 25 columns but you are trying to convert it into a 8 columns dataframe, which fails. Show `profit` content.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Pandas.

Use Spark to directly query RDS using `spark.read.jdbc`. Then, your schema will be automatically inferred from the database itself.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Otherwise, look at the koalas library, which has `from_pandas` function

https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/pandas_pyspark.html